# How Splash Screen Images Are Not Distorted In Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I Creating A Splash Screen In Xamarin Forms.
Did I follow the instructions: https://www.xamarinhelp.com/creating-splash-screen-xamarin-forms/

I've added the full image sizes to the respective folders:

- MDPI is 320×480 dp = 320x480px (The Default x1)
- HDPI is 1.5 x MDPI = 480x720px
- XHDPI is 2 x MDPI = 640x960px
- XXHDPI is 3 x MDPI = 960x1440px
- XXXHDPI is 4 x MDPI = 1280x1920px

and Drawable e folder for image size: 320x480px

However, the image is distorted build Android. I do not really understand. Can you help me with the solution? Tks.

[image]

[image]

This is how I use the [Simple nine-patch generator](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html). But it still seems distorted

[image]

Comment: Where did you put your images? Could you please post the screenshot of your resource folder? Besides, have you used android 9-Patch Image  for your app?

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have updated the content to be more clear. You can consider

Comment: Is it convenient for you to share a basic demo to github or onedriver so that we can test on our side?

Comment: Yes, Tks bro, Link Driver Google: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ZEGoSRilp3vfsavyV-WD-L0YwXnTNoVY?usp=sharing

Comment: I tested on my side, the image is not distorted but it's not in the middle of the screen. I think the size of the image is not suitable.

Comment: Can you help me with the solution?

Comment: You can try to put the souce image (in low density folder) into the high density,and generate the other images for different density  images.